# Random Number in Power Query with query folding

Tags: powerquery

I need to generate a column of random numbers in power query. Each row has to have a new value.

Is there a way to do this without breaking query folding??

```
Number.Random()
```

returns the same random value for all rows in the table (until query folding is broken)

```
Number.RandomBetween(x+[index]-[index], y)
```

breaks query folding.

```
List.Random(1, SEED){0})
```

only works (i.e. doesn't break query folding) with a static seed, which kind of defeats the purpose...

Any suggestions as to how I can go about doing this would be greatly apreciated?

Cheers,

Oscar

Comment: What kind of connector are you using?

Comment: I'm connecting to an SQL database using Power BI